# Query for related members

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, relationship

Please pardon me if I am unable to describe my question properly because I am confused about it.

I am trying to show related members to the one whose details page is opened. For this, I have a members table:

```
memID  |  name
1       |  Tom
2       |  Shawn
3       |  Bill
```

And a table to associate/relate members with each other, where mem1 value is memID of member whose details page is being used to associate the member like member.php?memID=1

```
recID  |  mem1  |  mem2
1      |  1     |  2
2      |  3     |  1
```

Now, the problem is coming when showing only related members on member details page where I am not finding a way to show only related members in array and not that member itself because I don't know in which field (mem1 or mem2) memID is saved of member, whose details page is opened.

For example, on Tom's page i.e member.php?memID=1, I would like to fetch names from members table of only related members, that are Shawn and Bill.

Comment: Pardoned. But see if you can do better.

Comment: @Strawberry I have tried and edited. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **MemID = 1**:

Try this:

```
SELECT m.memID, m.name, A.recId 
FROM member m 
INNER JOIN (SELECT recId, mem2 AS memID FROM relatedMembers WHERE mem1 = 1
            UNION 
            SELECT recId, mem1 AS memID FROM relatedMembers WHERE mem2 = 1
           ) AS A ON m.memID = A.memID
```

Comment: You are amazing really, excellent. If I could, I would give you hundred thousands points for this, because you understood question which myself was not able to understand when I read it again. ;)

Comment: just another question. Is there a way that in between this query I can also get the recID, so if I have to delete that relation, I can do that?